# How do i select 4 rows from a table holding 10 rows of persons based on the youngest age?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets say i have a table containing these rows

```
id  age
1   5
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   3
6   1
```

How do i write a select statement that selects exactly 4 of the youngest persons?

Answer (score 2):

You would use `top` and `order by`:

```
select top (4) t.*
from t
order by age asc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but Top(4) will get me 4 random rows. I want the 4 youngest persons

Comment: @N.Badaltjauwdharie it works for me http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/175736/1

Comment: @N.Badaltjauwdharie . . . `TOP (4)` would not give four *random* rows.  Without an `ORDER BY`, it would give four *indeterminate* rows -- something very different.  With the `ORDER BY` it gives the rows with the smallest age.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, age
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY age
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```